# Why heap corruption happened?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-corruption

I have an Unroll Linked List

```
class UnrolledLinkedList {
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
    int size; //num of elements in List
    int numOfNodes;
    int nodeSize;
}
```

with Node like this

```
class Node {
private:
    int maxElements;
public:
    int numElements; // number of elements in this node, up to maxElements
    int* elements; // an array of numElements elements,
    Node *next; // reference to the next node in the list
    Node *prev; // reference to the previous node in the list
}
```

And I want to put elements in an array. This is my funtion:

```
int* UnrolledLinkedList::toArray() {
int* arr = new int(size);
Node* pTemp = head;
int i = 0, j = 0, temp = 0;
while (pTemp) {
    i = 0;
    while (i < pTemp->numElements) {
        if (i != 0) j++;
        *(arr + j) = pTemp->elements[i];
        i++;
    }
    pTemp = pTemp->next;
    j++;
}
return arr;
}
```

And When I called this

```
int* arr = list->toArray();
int n = list->getSize();
printf("The list after converted to array:\n");
            if (n > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
                printf("\n");
                delete[] arr;
            }
            else {
                printf("NULL\n");
            }
```

in main, it caught an error HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED at line `delete[] arr;`
Please help me!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You do `Node* pTemp = head;
int i = 0, j = 0, temp = 0;
while (pTemp) {` but `head` may not have been initialized. You ought to initialize all your pointers. In-class initialization would do the job here, so `class UnrolledLinkedList {
    Node* head;` would become `class UnrolledLinkedList {
    Node* head = nullptr;`

Comment: @JesperJuhl OP doesn't show the code to construct the linked list, nor how new nodes are added.  However, the code snippets shows clearly where the problem is, assuming that these operations were implemented correctly, and even with everything initialised as you suggest.

Answer (score 10):

The following statement doesn't work as you think:

```
    int* arr = new int(size);
```

It creates a single `int`, intialized with the value `size`.

Your code will certainly work better with:

```
    int* arr = new int[size];
```